# Handling a user that continues to ignore guidelines

Tags: discussion, questions, users

In one of the tags I frequently visit there is a user that will post questions multiple times per day to a point where it seems as though I'm serial downvoting them.

The questions are always in the same format of "just got an error, here's the stack trace, go fix please", or at least that's how I interpret them.

Research is always non-existent (in fact they once asked an entirely different question less than an hour after another which to me shows they couldn't have researched the problem enough) which is what most of my downvotes attribute to, a lot of the questions are code dumps, but despite downvoting and multiple different approaches at asking them to create MCVEs and to read the How to ask page nothing changes.

For reasons that baffle me, their reputation does seem to grow or stay steady which I can only imagine comes from accepting the occasional answer they do receive or write themselves. This indicates to me that I'm getting closer to a serial vote reversal than they are to a question ban.

It seems to be frustrating for all involved here since the user will leave comments about why people downvote without commenting (I'm not the only one) and it seems clear that current efforts won't actually make any difference. So I'm wondering if theres anything else I could do that would make all involved more informed or do I just continue to vote/close in the same respect on their *low quality* posts? (I would upvote if anything was worthy)

Comment: Just carry on downvoting questions that aren't useful/lack research effort and voting to close questions that meet the criteria for being closed. I don't really think there's anything else you can do; the community has the tools to handle this so it doesn't seem appropriate to involve a moderator.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - that may solve the problem for me to a point but not so much for the user in question (I'd imagine). I too don't see what moderator involvement would achieve and it may well just be that I either need to ignore this users posts or carry on as you say.. Figured I'd ask if anyone else had experience in this situation or something along those lines.

Comment: I've run into a problem-user like that three times before.  They tend to survive by writing well enough.  Moderators are receptive but you have to let them know.  Use a custom flag on one of his questions that says something like "Is there anything you can do to slow this user down?  The quality of his contributions are consistently low".  I think they follow up by warning the user and, if necessary, by giving them a question ban.

Comment: @HansPassant - That sounds promising, just out of curiosity, how successful did you find it with in those 3 instances? I might try that on their next code dump

Comment: If you're referring to the user I think you are then I suggest you do as @Hans says (to confirm my suspicion and to put it formally into the mod review queue) with a brief description and a link to this meta post for reference. Cheers.

Comment: It was always successful in those 3 cases.  Two bans and they didn't come back after the ban expired, one appeared to have taken the warning in stride.  I of course cannot promise the same outcome in your case.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thats good to know, I wouldn't want to see them banned (unless deemed suitable) but I would love to see them have some reflection on their posts which would allow them to get better feedback/enjoyment. Jon Clements, I have flagged now as suggested by Hans

Comment: @Sayse thanks... (and yay, I did get the right user :p)

Comment: @JonClements - Woo, I'm glad it was clear whom it may be :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following Hans Passant and Jon Clements advice I flagged the user, at which point I'm guessing the user received some kind of ban (I don’t know) which lead them to use a second account to circumvent the ban and initially continue to ask questions in the same light.

Since then however, the account I flagged has been deleted and now the user has improved the quality of their posts so they're only just *marginally* not bad questions (still not good questions, but they're better).

So now I continue to treat this user as any other, but at least I'm not finding I'm downvoting all their content any more.