# Repeated questions from the same OP, how to react?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, sock-puppets

There is a user who is now at least into their fourth sock puppet who wants to decode `base64` in Procmail.

I will mention here that I have been an active Procmail user for close to 20 years and am the author of a once-popular FAQ on the subject, and I have never come across this specific use case before.  There are lots of situations where you have `base64` in email which needs to be decoded, but this particular case calls for a single token out of a specific body part.

Now, repeated questions about this very specific topic were originally asked by a user called [Robot Pepper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4747002/robot-pepper), then switched to [Amy X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4292942/amy-x), and now [Creativeit Design](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6047712/creativeit-design).  In addition to being repetitive, the questions typically omit all code formatting (in spite of multiple pointers to the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) and one or both of a test message and the log output from Procmail, which are required for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

By puzzling together these related questions, I managed to solve the problem to my own satisfaction, but these questions just keep on coming.  I have decided that I am unable to contribute further, seeing as things I have already repeatedly answered come up again in new questions.  I guess it would be fair to assume some part of the OP's circumstances have changed so that the posted answers are not applicable as such, but extracting useful diagnostics from the OP was challenging in the past, and so I have basically given up on that approach.

I have repeatedly marked questions as duplicates, but many remain open.

Now, the latest incarnation is ten steps back instead of just one or two: It's really generic, and shows no sign of any previous exposure to the topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018724/how-to-decode-64-in-email-attachment-with-procmail

I am posting this here for documentation and discussion.

Is it okay for this user to continue to post on a topic which by any reasonable judgment has already been resolved?

Is there anything more I should do besides ignore the questions except to flag duplicates when I see them?

---

For the 10k readers, here are some links to deleted questions, by yet another sock puppet (which I think used to have a name similar to Creativeit Design).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495966/detect-and-decode-base64-in-email-attachment
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566617/how-to-detect-and-decode-base64-email-attachment
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713416/decode-64-email-attachment-from-procmail

Comment: I wonder just why this guy keeps asking the same question with varying degrees of specification?

Comment: @Magisch The question kept me awake for a number of nights.  Speculation came up blank so far.

Comment: It is not so hard to understand—he keeps posting the same question because he hasn't gotten a satisfactory answer. Lots of users do this. And he has to subtly modify the question each time he asks it, because otherwise the system would block him from submitting it because that question already exists verbatim. (cc @mag)

Comment: @CodyGray What about the normal and recommended channels of getting a good answer, such as clarifying the question further or setting a bounty? Making more accounts en masse seems inefficient and vastly more work to me.

Comment: Could also be that this question was given as an assignment to a class and multiple people had the idea of offloading it to SO but didn't check for dupes first. (cc @CodyGray)

Comment: New users don't have sufficient reputation to set a bounty. None of these people have 50 reputation. It takes minimal effort to gain rep, and some users are not willing to expend the effort. Aside from that, they may not even know about the bounty feature. Lots of people don't read the help files. As for editing to improve clarity, you've seen as well as I have all the people who come to Meta insisting that their question is clear and all the people who downvoted it must not have bothered to read it. Everything you say is clear in your own head.

Comment: @Magisch I find it highly unlikely that any school would be teaching Procmail, let alone then not give students the necessarily parts to solve this particular problem.  This reminds me of [programmers can't program](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/), though.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not advocating this behavior, I'm just saying it's not inexplicable either. People who are unfamiliar with Stack Overflow's model often fail to use it correctly or get the most out of the site. Yes, it's also possible that this is a homework assignment, but tripleee already said it is a very unusual request, so that seems fairly unlikely. Impossible to be sure, of course.

Comment: @CodyGray Could also be that a bunch of people are stuck at this in the same company, and had the same idea but didn't bother to check. What I mean is we shouldn't assume as granted that these are sockpuppets, until confirmed by a mod.

Comment: @Magisch Similarities in posting style and approach made me link these accounts as sock puppets right from the start. It is unlikely that a department would consist solely of people who remove a crucial detail or incorrectly transcribe a solution and then are stymied when the change breaks a working piece of code.

Comment: @tripleee never attribute to malice that which can be adequately explained by stupidity. (Hanlon's Razor)

Comment: Could he be a bot? (Sorry I can't comment with my amount of rep)

Comment: To briefly address this possibility, the esoteric topic of these questions would make this a very unsatisfying bot experiment.  They are basically playing with the minds of three or four people, where you *could* be reaching all of Stack Overflow.  If I wanted to do some A/B testing, I would be in [tag:php] (... where allegedly many posts are challenging the Turing test).

Comment: Not technically a duplicate but I had a similar issue: [Handling a user that continues to ignore guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310529/1324033)

Comment: Robot Pepper is back again, now on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/1163177/does-procmail-write-to-maildir-or-var-mail-user

Comment: Posted a meta on SU: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/12005/apparent-sock-puppet-asking-repetitive-questions

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is it okay for this user to continue to post on a topic which by any reasonable judgment has already been resolved?

No.

> Is there anything more I should do besides ignore the questions except to flag duplicates when I see them?

I would rather raise a custom moderator flag explaining the sockpuppetry and duplication.

Comment: Thanks, I raised a moderator flag with a pointer to this question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the latest post -- which I link to from the question -- is deleted by Community now.

Comment: Presumably the issue is that the topic is so specific, not enough people are either reading the question or are expert enough to _know_ if it's a duplicate?

Comment: As an aside, one can always dupe-close a question from the same account, no need for any answers. Things get worse when sock-puppets enter the fray.