# A stream of similar questions from two different users

Tags: discussion

Today I came across two users working their way through SO to fix all of their problems in one snippet of code one by one via help from others.

1. It seems to start with [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092856/put-a-icon-on-graph-c3-js-d3-js?s=3|4.9990), where they start with a small code snippet. Another user answers the question and user #1 starts asking more and changing requirements in the comments.
2. Then a few days later [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122564/adjust-text-to-not-leave-the-screen-c3-js-d3-js?lq=1) follows.
3. Afterwards we're introduced to the user #2 with [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123326/create-a-tag-text-part-of-the-word-is-cut-c3-js-d3-js?lq=1), once again catching help from the same individual. Here user #2 says in a comment: "if you help me with this answer, I finally finish doing what I need [link to second question by user #1]", suggesting these might just be two accounts by the same person.
4. The helpful individual goes on to answer second question as well, but is clearly starting to get frustrated with the duo.
5. Since this has proved such a productive ordeal, [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161744/animation-bar-charts-in-c3-js-d3-js) and [fifth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170337/put-2-first-letters-in-bold-in-c3-js-d3-js) questions appear soon after.
6. When fourth question gets answered, user #1 comments: "I invite you to help me in this question that I try to put my problem. [link to question by user #2]"
7. Today the duo is back with both posting a question containing the exactly same snippet, making it [sixth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272582/put-a-spinner-c3-js-d3-js) and [seventh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272660/generate-an-animation-with-data-update-in-c3-js-d3-js) questions.

Reading through all the questions it doesn't seem like there's much research done by these two, so they don't really strike me as very high quality questions. Yet they get upvoted, so unlikely to enter LQ queue. So mostly I'm just not sure how to deal with these. Walk away and mind my own business, flag it to moderators (what's the offense against site rules though? impersonating each other?) or something else?

Comment: Some people think Stack Overflow is a super IDE with super code completion which will super magically complete or fix any code.

Comment: My guess? Classmates. Any rules about classmates asking similar questions on the same topic? No. What should you do when you smell something fishy? Flag it, or move on. Moving on is never the wrong thing to do.

Comment: ^ If they were by the same person, you would probably see one of them answering the other's question, since using two accounts like that would be kinda pointless.

Comment: @Majora320 or someone just doesn't grasp how this site works. Or someone wants to get around the time limit. Or they're doing it for giggles.

Comment: Not enough Meta downvotes :)

Comment: Reminds me of my ["friend" with the sock puppets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319065/repeated-questions-from-the-same-op-how-to-react).

Comment: Although it doesn't preclude classmates, they both lost upvotes from "User removed" on Feb 18. I don't understand the Jan 15 reputation entry for 011ce. Timeline says Up 1 Down 0, no other votes, matched by question itself, yet reputation seems to show +15 consisting to two +5s?

Comment: Be careful with those "Meta downvotes" that you are (a.) considering each question individually (not voting against the pattern) and (b.) not setting yourself up for a serial voting reversal.

Comment: I've hit the last couple with some close votes - they read as a pretty much "how do I do this?" question without showing previous attempts etc.

Comment: Isn't it possible that it's the same person logging in from different locations, perhaps not even realizing they're using different accounts?  One's logged in at work/school, the other at home...

Answer (score 2):

There are some good ideas in the comments.

I'm not convinced someone should go through the trouble of making two accounts look so different (IP addresses etc) just to play tag team. In my experience, even people who use Stack Overflow "as an IDE" still have to be able to put the pieces together.

While it's possible that the accounts in questions are classmates or the same person logged in from two places, speculation probably isn't going to solve this.

As far as rules being broken, there may not be any. The one which warrants investigation here is sock puppetry, but that's something a someone with superpowers would have to do.

I think a simple email saying "hey, do you know anything about this?" is a good place to start. "We don't know that this is breaking any rules, but someone brought it up on meta and we wanted to make sure that a) you didn't have some issue with your account and b) that there are no sockpuppets. Would you mind clearing this up?"