# Repeated question by the same OP - how often to flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

In one of the tags I follow, a specific user keeps asking basically the same question. After his question is usually down- and close-voted and doesn't receive an answer (as it's missing an MCVE), he deletes it - and posts it again with minor edits.

I have seen this happen last Friday and moderator-flagged one of them for the behaviour (according to *[Repeated questions from the same OP, how to react?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319065/repeated-questions-from-the-same-op-how-to-react)*). The flag was marked helpful, and I didn't see more of this question that day.

Today this pattern happens again (same user, same question, at least the second occurrence today), and I have moderator-flagged his question again, but I had to ask myself how often I should moderator-flag them as I don't want to waste too much moderator time.

- Once is enough; Big Brother is likely watching him and will intervene?
- Flag it once in a while, e.g. every day this happens?
- Flag every post I see to stop it quickly?
- Other?

I do also close-vote his questions (off-topic, lacking MCVE).

Comment: Explain in the flag that this keeps happening. If they want you to stop they can always mod message you.

Comment: We won't necessarily be "big brothering" a user for such things - we'll most likely give the benefit of the doubt and message a user and ask they stop re-posting the same question. If they continue to do so, then feel free to flag again and state it's happening again and we'll review it. Your flag text was pretty much spot on. Anyway - this specific case is handled.

Comment: Is there really a need to flag? The user will eventually be question banned if the behaviour persists.

Comment: When facing an agent who is replicating him self, I comment as soon as a duplicate is found use the `[edit]` to make him aware that he can edit the question. And to make sure we don't get an answer on every dupe. Then (few hours) I down vote every non answered post and raise a dupe flag on the worst version of the question. Imo mod flag is the be nice Policy. When you bring Agent Smith to meta you can be sure that meta effect gonna figth back. And it will ends in a Neo question ban!

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. So it seems raising a flag again after the previous one was handled is fine? Dare to put that as an answer?

Comment: @J.Steen The user in question had a number of upvoted posts, so it might have taken a lot of time before he got question banned. I'm not sure if most of the questions were actually closed before deletion and didn't have a huge number of downvotes.

Comment: @PierreLebon There was no chance to dupe-vote as previous questions were deleted.

Comment: @SebastianProske Fair enough.

Comment: I have certainly seen two individuals this week who have posted the same questions again and again after not getting much replies due to bad structure/description of their questions. An even more ridiculous story is one of the two individuals actually created multiple accounts and posted he same question across the site.

Comment: Multiple account is a common thing! Upon those Gremlins. They can even upvote their old dupe. But as a personal anecdote, The worst case I encounter was an OP than get a perfectly working answer 1 hour after his post. But because the name in the code was different he fails to apply it. And keep reposting the same question over and over. As it was on a low tag I let him live for 2 days.

Comment: @Pierre *I let him live for 2 days*... err... should I get worried about what that implies? ;-)

Comment: @JonClements, *Inner me:Hide the skin* - Wasn't me! *Inner me:look down look down, it's a Diamond.. They can feel your fear* - Do I have to get a new identity Again ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Generally given a (first) flag, if we agree with what you've raised, we may choose to message the user addressing concerns and how to improve (which is invisible to everyone except the user and the site moderators - so while it may appear nothing has happened - it may well have). In most cases, that's all that needs doing and everyone can move on.

Despite rumours we can't keep an eye on every user, so if you notice repeat behaviour, then please flag mentioning you've previously noted the behaviour and it's currently ongoing - we'll take a look.

Comment: So your telling me the feeling of being watched is all in my head and the tin foil hat does NOTHING?!?

Comment: @NathanOliver He tries to trick you, so keep your hat on.

Comment: No trickery at all. Although if you're going to keep your tin foil hat on @Nathan I'd suggest changing your top - they're not particularly colour coordinated :)

Comment: lol.  Nicely done sir.