# Individuals flooding the site with off-topic/too broad questions that show no effort to solve themselves

Tags: discussion

This question [Describe the conceptual model for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406234/describe-the-conceptual-model-for-a-website?noredirect=1#comment62320139_37406234) is what got me investigating the person's behavior in other questions because of their comment and refusal to edit their question.

What I found is what prompted me to make this *discussion* post on meta because it appears that their posts are *devolving* over time, to what is posted below.

Sorry I did not realize this got deleted, it is what prompted this post. Here it is for those that can not see deleted posts.

[image: don't care about the rules, answer my question!]

Their response is basically **"I haven't tried anything but copy and pasting what I was asked here so I can copy paste the answer back to my teacher"**. That and no attempt at editing the question to show effort or even improve the question in the least bit prompted my curiosity about their past behavior. Where there is smoke ...

This [person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5814438/33ted) is just posting off-topic presumably research study questions with no code, just requirements. As well as off-topic questions that are not even programming related, they are theory related and should be somewhere else instead. They are almost exclusively **too broad** to be fixed.

It seems that everyone of them gets an answer and is accepted, I can't go down voting all the off-topic stuff or I will get banned and leaving comments does not seem to matter. Most of the stuff is blatantly off-topic and/or duplicates.

**Opinions on how to deal with people like this when *voting on content not the person* is not effective.**

Comment: They look like questions from an algorithmic course... Isn't there another stackexchange site where they should belong ?

Comment: This is actually impressive... All of his homework is a question...

Comment: Maybe some questions are more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com. But not all users realize that site exists; they just know about Stack Overflow for programming Q & A.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Also related: [Should Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) be awarding “A”s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/178816)

Comment: Related: [Handling a user that continues to ignore guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310529/1324033)

Comment: Not terribly obvious how somebody could "flood" a site by posting 15 questions in 4 months.  The targeted downvoting you triggered is certainly a cure that's **much** worse than the disease, those are  *trusted* users that are abusing the site.  He'll eventually get question-banned anyway, this does not require a posse.

Comment: Flooding, 15 questions in 4 months ? I looked at a few of his questions and could not see any comments from you (`leaving comments does not seem to matter`). Did you mention **to him** he should post on [programmers.se] or you are only mentioning this here? You should probably include a link to one of the questions where you commented in a constructive manner and it was ignored.

Comment: I've seen a lot worse. At least some of his questions appear to be concise and well explained. Better than some users who simply write *stuffs not works* over and over.

Comment: What the hell is programming if not the application of [algorithm theory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36488968/542251)..

Comment: @bg17aw **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**. Recommended reading: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)
"A good question on Programmers.SE would be a good question on Stack Overflow..." etc

Comment: 13 questions in 4 months is not "flooding" a site with 5000 questions a day.

Answer (score 44):

Let's get this out of the way: [**asking about algorithms is *not* off-topic here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  At a bare minimum, those types of questions can find a home both here and at [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Now, let's talk about the quality of the questions, which I suspect is why you're bringing this up.

- Of their 15 visible questions, 11 appear to be about algorithms in some central way.
- Of these 11 algorithm questions:

  - **All** of them have a positive answer score,
  - **All except one** have a concrete question being asked, whereas all but maybe one include examples of their algorithmic or programmatic approach.

Do the questions directly benefit the OP?  *Absolutely*.  Do they *solely* benefit the OP?  No.  Does it make sense to close/delete them all?  **Not in the slightest.**  At least, not with the reasons being expressed.

[Take this one for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37131759/1079354)  It has a concise and well-explained answer to it, yet it's closed because *it's missing code?*  What the heck?!

[What about this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488968/1079354)  This question is still on-topic for the site!  There's really no reason to have closed it.

Most of these questions would benefit from some editing, and a few that *aren't* as clear could do with some sprucing up from the OP, but that doesn't make them off-topic.

---

I'm thinking in this scenario that you should probably chill out on the "blatantly" off-topic thing.  Algorithms have their place here as well, and it doesn't make much sense to punish askers senselessly for asking these questions.

Comment: Allright with that, but what did the guy tried to answer this question ? Nothing, besides copy/pasting the question to SO. So maybe not Off-Topic, but Too Broad ? OK he's got good answers because somebody was willing to do the job he didn't want to do, but the fact that the questions are poorly written stays on...

Comment: At least a couple of these are fairly unclear though. Like, with [the post-order traversal question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488968/post-order-graph-traversal) you linked - I have no idea how that's answerable. I'm not even sure in what way the answer corresponds to the question, given how vague the question is. It does appear to have been taken out of a textbook, but an awful lot of the vital context has been left behind. I don't know about voting to close as off topic, but I'm sure voting to close some of these for other reasons like this.

Comment: @SuperPeanut:  [What's so broad about it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323721/1079354)

Comment: @doppelgreener:  Just because you don't have an understanding of how a question is answerable doesn't imply that *someone else* doesn't.  The answer does a decent job of pointing one in the right direction on how the answer was what it was; perhaps you could leave a comment to the answerer to clarify their point?

Comment: OK not too broad then. But what ? Do you then accept the fact that a user can post his homework without any background, without any effort showed to answer it by himself? Look at the question scores, they are not well received because of these reasons. If people answer it to get rep or because they like to solve problems is Ok, but what impact does this have on the overall question quality ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut:  [It doesn't matter if these are homework questions.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308252/1079354)  Further, what other effort are you really looking for in solving these kinds of problems?  The ***vast majority*** of these questions show effort.  What were you looking for exactly?

Comment: From [How do I ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) : Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Here there is not shown effort to solve it by him/her self. In the question you linked, I didn't see any "I tried this or that, but can't achieve it.".

Comment: @SuperPeanut:  Let me rephrase my question.  How do you show "effort" when saying, "I'm not sure I understood this algorithm or its result.  Here is the initial graph, its initial traversal, and the other traversal I didn't understand.  How did it arrive at this other solution?"  I don't really see any more effort *required* since we have the original graph, we see its directions, and we have a concise answer as to how that solution came about.

Comment: When I say putting no effort, I also mean didn't even bother to search it on Google... Type in `Graph post order traversal` and you find lots of website explaining how to this kind of traversal. He could have said "I have been looking here but don't understand this", his question could have been "Why is node 3 coming last ?". This is, I think, the minimum effort. You're right and it's not worth a closing, but still the question are definitely not good, as no previous research has been made.

Comment: @Makoto: first, I'm not disagreeing with your central points. You said not to close the questions for the reasons of topicality expressed and I'm inclined to agree. Now, also, an expert looking at a question and considering it very unclear is the time we use the unclear close reason, so I don't think "someone else might understand it" is sufficient. If it should be useful to others, it should be understandable to them too as a question, right? I'll consider whether there's a comment I can leave on the question to request clarification in some way.

Comment: How do we deal with a misleading question that talks about **flooding** in a situation where a user posted 15 questions in 4 months? And when although the OP mentions "comments does not seem to matter" but there does not seem to be a lot of comments from him?

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems to me that a lot of moderators here are looking at reasons to close a question before thinking about the benefits of the question and the answer. Also there is the constant feeling that someone asking a question for his homework is a bad thing. Do you think that most people here ask questions for fun? Why is it different than someone having a question about his code at work? I agree with this answer, most of the posts that you qualify as "blatantly off-topic" are actually valuable posts that could benefit other people too.

Comment: And if I may add, I find answers on algorithmic questions A LOT more useful than answers on pure code debugging that you see all around. Less "code oriented" questions tend to attract "thinkers" who provide in-depth explanations and opens valuable discussions about best practice, optimization etc

Comment: no, not **All of them have a positive answer score**, i think meta effect has worked.

Answer (score 9):

This is certainly a sort of edge case scenario. There is a user who is creating questions which are for the most part only going to benefit themselves.

In my opinion they are upper division computer science questions from an undergrad student.

The questions seem to contain just enough context that certain mind reading users can post answers that satisfy the OP.

With the views low and the overall intent positive, is this exact situation a problem? Is the overall pattern a problem if it is prevalent? Is it prevalent?

These are some of the issues I think would have benefited addressing this topic that I don't see in the post here. In my opinion had these posts in question received more attention *some* of them probably would have been closed.

However, is meta effect nuking these with the power and precision of community ire really going to solve the overall problem, or will it just make some feel better without addressing the underlying issue.

Namely, the issue being that there is not enough oversight available on posts which do not receive enough attention. This has been a problem for a very long time until we swept it under the rug (i.e. put a lifespan on close votes). If you have a solution to that problem, please don't keep it to yourself.

Comment: Well, IMHO, Copy/pasting an assignment without writing what you've tried will not make a good question. Besides that, many of these are really off-topic as they are refering to a math problem...

Comment: @SuperPeanut - I agree, and above in a comment on this post I linked a very large discussion revolving around the idea of "effort" and including what you've tried. I also do not think many of these posts will survive after the increased attention, but in general without someone like Jarrod noticing this somewhat complex pattern, how can this be addressed?

Comment: -1 because I'm not really sure what you are saying.

Comment: @djechlin - Fair enough, but it would help if you at least articulated which aspect you did not understand.

Comment: There's no answers in your answer, only questions and acknowledgment you don't know the answers.

Comment: @djechlin - There is not a question being asked either. Just an allusion to a broader topic with a thinly veiled attempt at invoking the meta effect. This was an attempt to at least direct some discussion to something constructive here. Also, I do not have an answer to a problem that has plagued this site for 6 years (nor does anyone else) - which is entirely different than not having the answer to this situation. While my response may be rhetorical in nature, the questions are for others to consider themselves instead of punishing this one user en masse which seems to be what happened.

Answer (score 7):

I'm poking through this user's post history and the conclusion I've come to is this:

- Some of the questions belong elsewhere, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524722/solve-recurrence-relation-by-master-theorem) is pure math.
- Some of these questions are off-topic and deserve closing (the [graph traversal question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488968/post-order-graph-traversal) is pure theory with no effort shown, for example).
- There are reasonable, [actual-code-shown questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518941/file-was-built-for-unsupported-file-format).
- Some of the questions asked are also just good stuff: well-received, well-written, and discuss topics SO users clearly find useful.

**Users need guidance, particularly new ones.** I don't see many comments on the off-topic posts suggesting "try this SE site" or "what work have you done so far?" Granted, giving many of us a pure theory question and we will dive in eagerly without thinking if the question is posed on the correct site (as evidenced by the thorough answers received). In this way, **we are partially to blame**. The devolution of question quality is evidence that we aren't effectively communicating the standards and expectations of SO where he/she has erred. The fact that the questions we are discussing took place over *months* only strengthens this argument.

Is this user perfect? No. Is the user "flooding" SO? Nope. Is this user deserving of the retroactive, blanketing downvote-and-close hammer on all of his questions that is MSO's ire? Definitely not. Selective pruning and guidance to the user are all that *I believe* is necessary at this point.

P.S.: Newcomer to meta, hello.

Comment: It is entirely possible this user asked a good question and got an answer. Then asked a not-so-good question .. and still got an answer! "Hey", went OP's thinking, "let's see just how low I can go". Yes: [Stack Overflow makes people lazy](http://nerdr.com/stackoverflow-makes-hackers-lazy/).

Comment: Agreed. And again, it's all about guidance on a per-question basis to ensure further questions are still good.

Comment: Also, that is a fantastic link. There's definitely a slippery slope into laziness.

Comment: Saying that several of the user's questions are offtopic or otherwise problematic, and then also saying it's wrong to go and closevote those questions us contradictory.  If the questions merit closure (and/or downvotes) then that's what should be done.

Comment: @Servy: I mean that those *specific* questions need addressing by downvote-and-close. I believe the OP is overreacting to a handful of questions over a multimonth period, when standard measures will do. `Selective pruning and guidance` is how I phrased it in my conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular situation, I feel the user's first questions were received fairly well; one of the questions in **January** even got 3 upvotes and has a clear, well-written answer that also has numerous upvotes.

If I looked correctly at all the questions, only one was opt to close with the reason:

> voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly
>   related to programming.

I feel like the person has been asking the same type of question since January, which at first was well received, but down the road has become less and less accepted. I feel they should have been prompted with more proper *What did you Try?* and *Error codes?*.

This person should receive the benefit of the doubt because their first moments at Stack Overflow led them to believe their questions were properly formatted. Which they clearly were not, but answers were being given, with some upvotes even.

When this type of poorly formatted/overly broad etc. question is asked, we as a community are obliged to not only downvote and move on. We should also leave a comment offering positive feedback to guide the user in the right direction.

A counterpoint to this argument might be that they should have read the help center, but I feel that giving a person advice in response to their poor or improper question is the least we can do as a community to try downsizing bad questions. If the advice is not followed, further measures can then be taken.

This particular *person* should have been advised properly from the beginning. All that can be done now is leave the past be, since not a lot of harm was done and now with their last question(s), and properly address the situation by guiding them in the right direction.

Comment: You made a lot of great points, so I edited it in the hope that it will be more clear. You get my upvote.

Comment: eh, idk, I'm pretty happy to downvote and move on. I answer other people's questions for free a lot of the time, I think that's good enough.

Comment: @djechlin And I strongly feel that is whats wrong. If you have the time to downvote you have the time to drop a one liner that states your reason. Since downvotes won't lead to the user understanding why.

Comment: It's *absolutely* not true that if I have time to downvote I have time to explain what's wrong. I can either filter out bad content on the site at large scale or educate a handful newbies on what they're doing wrong, which I firmly feel usually goes to waste, and also opens the risk of getting dragged into a trolly internet argument about whether their question was crappy or not.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/1339987

Comment: @djechlin I agree with you but as I called it positive feedback, there it states constructive feedback. It can be helpful if you leave it you are not obliged to.

Answer (score 1):

The questions here are to be asked and telling the user they have to post on Programmers.SE might not help.

```
A lot of the user's answers seem to have been closed
```

which could be a problem but a lot of that could be solved if somebody told the user they have to edit their questions fully before they post them although it should be ok for people to edit them up as well.

Mostly it is not a problem for the site and few people seem to think it is, though

```
we need to make sure things don't get worse.
```

```
I recommend leaving some comments for the user to let them know
they need to pay a bit more care and attention to what they are posting
and not be too quick to post without checking but tell them they are still
welcome on Stack Overflow too.
```

Answer (score -5):

I think we overlooked an important fact here. This user has not ***answered*** any questions.

This is a strong indication of help-vampirism. I'm not sure what the deal is with this user in particular, maybe they use another account to answer questions (an acceptable practice, not that I like it).

The fact that they bothered with grammar and such gives them a slight edge over others in my mind. But I have been editing a lot of ungrammatical messes lately and I am probably biased.

It's hard to tell, from the questions I read, if they are just here for the answers or if they actually *want* to learn. Do they indicate interest in the answers beyond the first correct answer they get?

As others have mentioned, these types of questions aren't technically off-topic for SO. I do feel, however, that some of these questions belong more on CS.SE for the simple fact that Stack Overflow does not support MathJax. Personally, I also feel that the wording of these questions can be exclusionary; many of us don't have the comp-sci background needed to understand the technical jargon used (I feel that I might otherwise be able to answer these questions). But there are experts here on the matter it seems, so that isn't an issue overall.

In any case, these questions are not the worst offenders. Instead of focusing on borderline questions, we need to close more questions that come here thinking that "anything remotely technical" == programming. At least this user isn't asking us to troubleshoot their wifi problems like we're some sort of customer service help desk.

Comment: I really don't care what goes on in the user's life besides the extent to which they write useful, answerable, at least slightly interesting questions here and possibly get answers.

Comment: Many Java questions require a Java background...  doesn't make them exclusionary. Or if it does, that's a pretty nonsense goal for SO to worry about...  only answering questions that everyone has opportunity to answer? Nope, not what SO is.

Comment: @djechlin Thank you for pointing that out; you seem to have interpreted what I said differently than what I intended, so I have clarified my wording. I'm not sure what you meant by "what goes on in the user's life", however. Could you clarify? I don't know this user, and I certainly haven't addressed anything outside the realm of SO...